# Which ECMAScript Version do the npm modules use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using some npm modules and I would like to know which ECMAScript version they need to run. I currently use the [brite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brite) module and have a problem with it. I think the problem is because the module needs a newer version, but I can't find any information about which it needs. 
Is there maybe a general specification for npm modules which version they are using?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. What exactly is the problem you're having? Like, what is/are the error(s)?

Comment: It depends on the module—your best bet is to look at the documentation

Comment: looks like ecma 4 for me, but can be 5 too

Comment: Start by telling us what version of node.js you are using.

Comment: My error is that it can't find the module, but I run the code on a platform and the error logs are not very detailed, so I thought that maybe that could be the problem. The platform uses ES3. So I just wanted to know which version the modules need and in the documentation I didn't find anything

Comment: @mtizziani ECMAScript 4 was abandoned, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#4th_Edition_.28abandoned.29

Answer (score 1):

It depends which modules. Some modules can use ES3, some can use ES5, some can use ES6 and some can even use ES2017. There is no one version of ECMAScript that all npm modules are written in but usually most of the modules should work on any reasonably modern version of Node. But keep in mind that not everything on npm is a Node module. The npm can be used to distribute some other code like frontend code or [even Perl scripts!](https://twitter.com/pocztarski/status/696835552792993792)

The npm package that you linked to in the question doesn't include the `engines` field in `package.json` that is used to specify the Node version that it requires - see:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines

It also doesn't have any automated tests that could verify which Node version it supports.

You didn't include two most important things in your question:

1. What errors do you get
2. What version of Node are you using

Other relevant info that you also didn't include:

- Did you test on the newest Node version?
- Does the problem still exist?

At this point you shouldn't really use any Node version older than 6.x which is the current LTS and preferably 7.x which is the current stable version. You can still use 4.x because it will still get a year of maintenance but there is no reason to. Version 5.x was not LTS so it's not supported any more. See the maintenance schedule of Node versions:

- https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#readme

To see the ECMAScript support of the versions of Node, see:

- http://node.green/

Comment: ok, so if they dont write the version in the documentation I have bad luck? I'm using node 4.5 and the browserify module to use the modules on the client side without node